# syncing : Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed error in syncing.... androidstudio 3.6.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java-11

I did not work with my `Android Studio` up today.
when I build my project and I synced it , it said : `Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:`

***I did not change anything in the project*** and the language of the project is `Kotin`.
I use `JDK 13` and `Android Studio 3.6.1` and the latest Android SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk
Use Jdk 8 as mentioned in above link.

Answer (score 15):

In short

> Set the JDK version to Embedded JDK

**WHY?**

A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2+. This is the JDK version GOOGLE recommend.

To use the bundled JDK, do the following:

**HOW?**

Android Studio > Preferences... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
Under Gradle JDK, choose the Embedded JDK option.
Click OK.

For windows

select File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
Under Gradle JDK, choose the Embedded JDK option.

Answer (score 7):

I'm too late, but it helps someone.

I got the same problem when I installed Android Studio 4.2.1 in Windows 10. I fixed it by selecting the JDK location.
Open File > Project Structure. Then select the SDK Location tab (on the left).
On the JDK location section, select Embedded JDK: option (the first one).

Look at this picture:

[image: Screenshot]

It worked in my case. Also, I'm using the latest Gradle Version (6.7.1) and Android Gradle Plugin Version (4.2.1).

Answer (score 5):

Change your `JDK` version by following steps in **Android Studio**:

**File**-> **Project Structure** -> `SDK` **location** -> `Gradle` **Settings**

Then select the configured `JDK` version.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I also experienced the same, I tried changing the JDK version.

1. File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> **Gradle**
2. Gradle JVM -> Download JDK

and I set it as below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved it change the version of Gradle on Project Structure options. I imagine it will also work by configuring old versions

[Gradle Version Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTddw.png)

Comment: you suggest to use which version?

Comment: I try with the newest for my new project Gradle version 6.2.1

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart and rebuild project after apply the config change

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while creating a new project, so I am telling solution for the case, if you are creating a new project and you got this error, then below mentioned solution will definitely work for you.

**Condition** : Check your project's name if it is having any special characters like ',#,@ etc.

**Solution** : Just remove any special character from the project's file name and that's it.

Comment: I used JDK-8 and my problem was solved.... thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If the situation is . you cloned an old repository , then they ask you to upgrade the Gradle wrapper version , after upgrading you go this error . It will mostly because you forgot to upgrade gradle version in app module too . Android studio doesnt do this automatically . For example you have 5.x.x . and you upgraded to 7.7 cause Android studio suggested it . The wrapper version changes but the project gradle version aka AGP version in build.gradle file might havent updated

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    }
}
```

check this

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error while creating a new project in a newly installed Android Studio, So i am sharing my solution-
If you have installed the very latest version of Android Studio then try installing the older version.
In my case i installed version 4.1.2 and was not able to make gradle work. So i uninstalled 4.1.2 version and tried 3.6 version and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:**

I also got this error while creating new project in Android Studio. I solved this by simply replacing below code:

1. **projectName/build.gradle** :

**from**

```
    plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
}
```

**to**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
}
```

2. **projectName/app/build.gradle**:

**from**

```
    plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
}
```

**to**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

3. **projectName\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties**:

> **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip**

Answer (score -1):

The error message you've posted appears to be related to Groovy, a programming language that runs on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The error message indicates that there was a problem with compiling or running a Groovy script.

Here's a breakdown of the error message:

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: This part of the error message indicates that there were multiple compilation errors during the execution of your Groovy script.

startup failed: This suggests that the script encountered an issue at the start of its execution, possibly during the compilation phase.